# Can the browser invalidate (valid) cache item if it's disk cache is full?

Tags: caching

Is it possible that if user with a full browser cache comes to my website and some my resources required to be cached (via Cache-Control header), then browser will remove some old (but still valid, i.e. non-expired) items from the cache in order to make it possible to cache my resources?
If there is no outdated resources in user's cache, will the  browser ignore my cache policy?

Answer (score 0):

If the cache is full the browser has to find room for new content somewhere.

A sane approach to this would be to

```
 1) first remove all expired contents.
 2) second remove oldest (based on time since last visit) contents
```

But, to be honest with you I have never looked deep into this issue because I find it counter productive to rely on cached contents. Many browsers have a "delete all cache on exit" button. Or the users run programs like CCleaner to remove temporary files. Cache is basically considered temporary files.

I suppose you could try writing a server log analyzer that would determine whether specific resources are being reloaded at a time when companion resources are not being loaded. This would involve separating the header-only call that is used to determine "age" of the resource vs. the full download of the resource. Again mostly speculation since, I don't rely on cache being there AND I don't use cache as a tracking device.